# How to Create an image in DeployStudio

Tags: macos, osx-server, server.app, software

I just installed DeployStudio v1.6.13 on OS X Server Yosemite.
Followed some directions to get everything installed and everything looks like it's working.
For example, another mac can boot into the network disk from the .nbi file i created.
I have a few issues however.

First, when I boot into Runtime, I get the error: "repository access error an error occured while mounting the repository share point"
I haven't found a real solution to that, and yes I set up the server as a network sharepoint for my repository. (I also put the the folder on file share available read and write to everyone and guests could access just to make sure that was not an issue)

Regardless, my workaround for now after trying so many things like checking my files are shared on the server etc, is to hit continue when I get the error then hit Command + R.

Now that I'm on Runtime how do I upload an image to this computer I just booted to the network with. Was the .nbi the image? Do I have to create something on the workflows? What is the process.

Please keep in mind that when I hit "Create a master from a volume" on any Mac it tells me that there is no volume available and then it has an arrow pointing to >>>>>>> Repository.
That's how I thought I would create the image but I can select a volume.
I hope that was enough info for someone to answer my question.

Please help and thank you in advance. :D

UPDATE: I resolved the repository issue (it was an issue with the url I provided for the network sharepoint).

Now I'm trying to create an image from an already set up computer with all applications I need. I booted from mini and it was able to create an image. I booted from a Pro, however, and the volume is grayed out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The .nbi is the NetBoot set, it's the disk you are booting the Mac you want to image from that contains DeployStudio Runtime. From there you will run a workflow, that can incorporate an image if you want. The workflow is created in DeployStudio Admin.

To create images, I like to use AutoDMG: https://github.com/MagerValp/AutoDMG

Once you get your image, you'll want to make sure it's named with a .hfs.dmg (AutoDMG will take care of this for you).

You copy the image on to your DeployStudio repo, by mounting the file share and copying the file into a folder called Masters and a subfolder inside that called HFS (I'm doing this from memory so that name may be slightly off).

Once your Master is in place, you should be able to select it from the Imaging step in a new workflow you create in DeployStudio admin.

Make sure the fileshare and its contents are accessible by the user you setup for DeployStudio... that may be the issue.

Comment: thanks for your answer. AutoDMG is a great tool and I'm going to use it for new images for sure... I got to fix my repository issue (a url change mess up) so I was just going to ask because I have a computer that already has all the applications I would want. I got the repository to work, but when I boot into the .nbi the volume is grayed out... I mean I tried to boot from a mini as a test and it created an image successfully and put it on the tmp folder...but when I boot from this pro the volume is grayed out...any suggestions?